# Change seed phrases

Tags: wallets, security, private-key

How I understand seed phrase is a secured phrase of my private keys.

And then I have a question:

If I create a wallet I get one seed phrase, one account and one private key.
If I push another private key in my wallet then it has two private keys (two accounts) then the seed phase has to change then I can recover my wallet with two accounts (two private keys) if I need.

Do I right understand this moment? The seed phase will change automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I create a wallet I get one seed phrase, one account and one private key.

Nearly. You get one seed phrase, but that can translate into multiple private keys, and therefore multiple accounts.

> If I push another private key in my wallet then it has two private keys (two accounts) then the seed phase has to change then I can recover my wallet with two accounts (two private keys) if I need

No - the seed phrase never changes.

---

The part you're missing is the idea of HD - hierarchical deterministic - wallets.

An HD wallet starts with a master key, which can be represented by a mnemonic. The master key - and therefore mnemonic - never changes.

From the master key you can then derive child keys, each representing a different account.

Background:

- Anything under the [hd-wallets](/questions/tagged/hd-wallets) tag
- [External]: [The Journey from Mnemonic Phrase to Address](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-journey-from-mnemonic-phrase-to-address-6c5e86e11e14)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hope now I understand right. Seed phrase already contains many, many... private keys and it gives me a new private from its own list when I need it. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct :-)

Comment: Also, I have a little question. For example, I have a wallet with seed phrases and I import another private key into it. So I understand when I'll recover my wallet with seed phrases it will not contain the imported private key and I have to import it again. Are my minds on the right way?

Comment: ...because the imported private key doesn't contain in the list of seed phrase.

Comment: Good question. Yes, you're correct :-) The imported private key won't be a key derived from the original seed phrase.